# Question about part of the proof of the fundamental theorem of calculus

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

So this is a question about really a very tiny technicality, here it goes:

The statement:

If $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and $f=g'$ for some function g, then $$\int_{a}^{b} f = g(b) - g(a)$$

Its proof goes as follows:

Let $F(x) = \int_{a}^{x} f$, then $F' = f = g'$ on $[a,b]$ (by the first part of the fundamental theorem of calculus), consequently there is a number C such that $F = g + C$, and to determine C, define $\int_{a}^{a} f = 0$, so $F(a) = 0$, substituting in the equation we get $$ 0 = F(a) = g(a) + C $$
so $C = -g(a)$, then we have $$F(x) = g(x) - g(a),$$
letting $x=b$, we arrive finally at the formula $$\int_{a}^{b} f = g(b) - g(a)$$

**My question is as follows:**

I feel we cheated a little, because integrals were first defined on an interval using lower and upper sums, so here we defined $\int_{a}^{a} f = 0$, so we have a value of $F(x)$ at $a$ so we can solve the equation.

But as I understand - please correct me if I'm wrong, and destroy my logic - up to before the mentioned proof, there was no necessity to define $\int_{a}^{a} f = 0$, it is just a conventional definition, it doesn't follow from the definition of the integral, up to this point we only deal with integral over an interval, not a single point.

After proving that $\int_{a}^{b} f = g(b) - g(a)$ we can say if we want this statement to hold when $a=b$ then  $g(b) - g(a) = 0$ so we define $\int_{a}^{a} f = 0$ to be consistent with the general result, so this definition follows from the theorem if we want to make it consistent, **so how can we use the this definition to prove the general result, isn't this some form of circular reasoning?**

In short, assume I don't care at all about how to define the integral over a single point, and that I only care about integrals over intervals with their properties which follow logically from the definition of the integral, then how to prove that the constant $c$ in the equation is equal to $-g(a)$ ?

I thought about it and my reasoning is as follows:

We have arrived at the result $F = g + C$ without caring about the definition of $F(x) = \int_{a}^{x} f$ at $a$, but it should be clear that the closer $x$ is to $a$, the smaller the interval over which we integrate, and indeed it is easy to prove that $\lim_{x \to a+} F(x) = 0$, so we have
$$ \lim_{x \to a+} F(x) = \lim_{x \to a+} g(x) + C$$

so $0 = \lim_{x \to a+} g(x) + C$, and since $g$ is differentiable (particularly differentiable at $a$, although I'm not sure how to prove this point or whether it is essential for the fundamental theorem to hold, may be it is enough that $g$ is differentiable at $(a,b)$ not $[a,b]$? Please help with this point) then $g$ is continuous at $a$ so $\lim_{x \to a+} g(x) = g(a)$ so finally we have $C = -g(a)$.

After that we can say that for convince we will define $\int_{a}^{a} f = 0$ so that the general result is consistent at the end point, or whatever.

Again, please correct me if I'm wrong and destroy my logic.

**Edit**

Below is a quote from Abott "Understanding analysis", in which he says that the integral over a single point is defined to be zero for convention
[image]

Comment: What is your definition of $\int_a^b f$? Presumably a limit of Riemann sums where you take a limit over finer and finer meshes of $[a,b]$. If so, there’s not that many meshes you can make out of $[a,a]$.

Comment: As you said, it is a limit of Riemann sums over an interval, or the unique number between all lower and upper sums over an interval, in either cases, integration over a single point is a doesn't follow logically from the definition, as far as I understand. For example in "understanding analysis" by Abbot, he explicitly defines the integral over a point to be zero and then says: "Deﬁnition 7.4.3 is a natural convention to simplify the algebra of integrals."

Comment: You can use properties of integrals and define $\int_{a}^{a} f=\int_{a}^{b} f+\int_{b}^{a} f$

Comment: An alternative route to this part of the FTC is to use the Mean Value Theorem and use Riemann sums directly...

Comment: Also, if you want the integral to be "the area u der the curve", then setting $\int_a^af(x)\,dx=0$ isn't a convenience, but a necessity: the area of a line segment is $0$.

Comment: $\int_{a}^{b} = - \int_{b}^{a}$ is a just a convenient definition, it doesn't follow from the properties of the integral, as Abbott said in understanding analysis: "Deﬁnition 7.4.3 is a natural convention to simplify the algebra of integrals".and he meant both defining $\int_{a}^{a} =0$ $\int_{a}^{b} = - \int_{b}^{a}$

Comment: @ArturoMagidin yes I know it can be proved using the mean value theorem and Riemann sums, but I'm asking about the mentioned proof whether it is logically valid or not

Comment: The empty sum is, by definition, equal to zero (it must be, to preserve associativity). The definition of an upper, lower, or Riemann sum applied to an interval of the form $[a,a]$ will necessarily yield $0$. It's not a "convenient convention", it's a consequence of the definition. There are no "logical issues" here.

Comment: I feel like the issue here isn't a logical one, but a pedagogical one. I.e., assuming properties instead of proving them. So I guess the answer is yes, you should feel slightly cheated, but no, there are no logical issues.